# iOS 7 animation becomes 0 duration after undetermined amount of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

This is an issue that I've been having since the first beta. I found two threads at the Apple Developer Forums with no solution to it, hoping someone might have the answer here.

Basically, all animations in the app becomes instant including `UINavigationController pushViewController` `UIViewController presentViewController` `UIView animateWithDuration` and etc. after some amount of time (between minutes and hours). I monitored the memory usage and it was fine and nothing came up in the logs. This happens on both the iPhone 5 and iOS Simulator and only on iOS 7.

I know it's not a lot of information, but the problem seems very elusive. I just want to note that the app does use CoreData heavily with GDC calling animation on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem. Maybe we can find the common points of problem.

Could you let me know which libraries you are using?

I my app with same problem is using following libraries

- AFNetworking
- HTProgressHUD
- MFSideMenu

Comment: I actually figured out the issue following some other questions on StackOverflow, it has to do with UI operations called on a background thread as a result of multi-threading I do with CoreData. I was able to narrow down the pieces of code by throwing an exception anytime a UIView is not on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that my problem was solved. I created HUD view on HTTP request run-loop.